# How to make if statement that checks if multple listBoxes are empty or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, listbox

How do I make an if statement that asks if multiple listBoxes are empty or not?

This is what I have so far...is it possible to combine it into one single if statement?

```
    if (listBoxEmails.Items.Count < 1)
    {
     //Perform action
    }

    if (listBoxWebsites.Items.Count < 1)
    {
    //Perform action
    }

    if (listBoxComments.Items.Count < 1)
    {
       //Perform action
    }
```

Comment: I want to check if each is empty. So I want the logic to be for the program to check is listBox1 is empty OR if listBox2 is empty OR if listBox3 is empty. I tried using the || for this but its not working.

Comment: @EdwinTorres What do you mean by empty? Text of listbox is empty or items count is zero,

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully that will help you,

Comment: Are all Perform Action same, then only its possible to integrate all three calls and perform the action, else you have to work on them separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (listBoxEmails.Items.Count >= 0 && listBoxWebsites.Items.Count >= 0 && 

    listBoxComments.Items.Count >= 0)
    {
    //perform action

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Simplest solution and it was exactly what I needed. All I did was replace the && with || and it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get a count from ALL list boxes on your form, you can do this:

```
if (Controls.OfType<ListBox>().Any(z => z.Items.Count < 1))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

The magic is that if you delete or add any more list boxes on your form, you won't have to change any code. If you want to grab specific listbox's, you could set the `Tag` property on all the listbox's you want included to something like `CountedListBox` and then do this:

```
if (Controls.OfType<ListBox>().Any(z => z.Items.Count < 1 && ((string)z.Tag == "CountedListBox")))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have list boxes in some collection and using linq you can find in one statement if the any of the list is empty or not. Something like this. Of course there can be different approaches for list box collections.

```
    private void ValidateListBoxes()
    {
        List<ListBox> listBoxes = new List<ListBox>();
        listBoxes.Add(listBoxEmails);
        listBoxes.Add(listBoxWebsites);
        listBoxes.Add(listBoxComments);

        bool isContainingEmptyList = listBoxes.Any(l => l.Items.Count < 1 || l.Items.Count==0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most simple solution I can think of,

```
if (listBoxEmails.Items.Any() && listBoxWebsites.Items.Any() && listBoxComments.Items.Any())
{
    // Do something here,
 }
```

Comment: Read the requirements from OP first. Thanks

Comment: It said there is no definition for .Any?

Comment: You need to add namespace for Linq,

Comment: I added using System.Linq and I still get this error: Error 5 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: First cast your items as ListItem then you can do any linq operation. e.g. lbxCustomers.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any()

Comment: The reason its not working is because it needs to be cast.

Comment: The "Any" extension method is not available with list box Item.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in WPF or WinForms? You could do:

```
    var performAction = (!listBoxEmails.Items.IsEmpty | !listBoxWebsites.Items.IsEmpty | !listBoxComments.Items.IsEmpty);
    if (performAction)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Winforms. I got an error using your code on the ".IsEmpty" part

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize you were using WinForms. I'll add the tag to your question